# Licensees of standard essential patents

Tags: licensing

Does anyone know of any lists providing the licensee of SEPs within a handful of industries (such as IoT, cellular, wifi and similar)?

I'm trying to investigate how SEP licensing fees may affect small business investment decisions. So far, I have found Qualcomm's licensee list, a patent pool from MPEG-LA, and a similar pool from Access Advance.

I would really appreciate if anyone knows anything else on this matter - as I'm trying to research this for my thesis.

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but this site has data for the numbers of SEPs : https://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=7b0f2d25-4a00-40d8-9de3-d57eb7990c30